# Find a Rectangle by coordinates - XNA

Tags: xna, vector, coordinates

I have 2 coordinates (X,Y). I have also a 10x10 array. By these coordinates I have to find the rectangle in which is my pointer at the moment.
How could I handle it?

Comment: This isn't stated clearly. Where did the pointer come into it? You already have two coordinates and you can calculate a rectangle from that.

Comment: Since he mentioned a `10x10 array` and the rectangle `in which the pointer is in` I guess he might be talking about having a tile grid on screen and figuring out which tile is under the *mouse* pointer. But yeah the question is very unclear, and we could use more information such as, where does the grid start.

Answer (score 1):

If your grid array is displayed as a Rectangle(ox,oy, 10*CELL_SIZE, 10*CELL_SIZE), where (ox,oy) is an offset...

then the cell coords are

```
  xCell = (x-ox)/CELL_SIZE;
  yCell = (y-oy)/CELL_SIZE;
```

of course you should check the coords are in right range (0..9,0..9)